# How to search the same object with different Equal concepts?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, equals, iequalitycomparer

I have several objects that depending on the use case are considered Equal differently.

I need to use these objects as keys for dictionaries and as far as I know `Dictionary<>` use the `Equals()` method which limits me to have only one implementation of it.

Is there any workaround to this? I expected to be able to inject a `EqualityComparer`, a delegate or something so `Dictionary<>` can use different ways of searching for items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any *one* dictionary can only have a single equality comparer. You can't ask it to find a key with respect to a particular equality comparer, because otherwise its stored hash codes will be useless, and it would have to just do a linear search.

If you have multiple equality comparers you want to search across, I'd keep several separate dictionaries, each with a different comparer.

(If you just wanted to be able to specify the equality comparer and had missed it, that's what the [`Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for).